# Image Transform rotate on each slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working slider, and it works perfectly but what I am looking for is different effect of what currently it has, Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/tdup1g2g/) Example

On each slide image is zooming out and I am looking for opposite effect, that will zoom-in instead of current effect, but unable to do it.

Code is following

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["https://cdn.img42.com/35f7070a6c188d7e325a8c93db7fec05.jpeg", "https://cdn.img42.com/42d703e80b91ac0d7b412e649f761af5.jpeg", "https://cdn.img42.com/e864ec05541d5f0adbc6b73063d05d5c.jpeg"]' data-zs-overlay="dots">
    <div class="demo-inner-content">
        <h1><span>Testing</span> . <span>Slider</span></h1>
        <p>Testing Slider Test Slideshow Test Slideshow Test Slideshow </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your slider is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the scale factor to desired value in css (here i did to `1.0`)

```
.zs-enabled .zs-slideshow .zs-slides .zs-slide {
    background: transparent none no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

and change the tween value to desired value (i did to `1.5`)

```
.css( { 'opacity': 1.0, 'transform': 'scale(1.5, 1.5)', 'z-index': 2 } )
```

updated fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tdup1g2g/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer on this, but actually images when it starts from center, what I am looking is it should show cover on screen from start like this working http://michaelelliott.co.uk/en/

Comment: i've updated the fiddle link, that's you are looking for i bet

Comment: @Özgür Ersil Nice1